# How to create a best algorithm for tha car race?

Tags: java

I should to implmenets an application to control a race of car.
So in a race I have for example 5 car. I want to know the position of this car in every turn, the last time, and best round for all car. Now I wanto to know what structure of data is the best solution for this.

I have create this object:

```
package Auto;

    import java.security.Timestamp;

    public class Macchina {
        Integer corsia;
        Integer giro;
        Timestamp ultimoTempo;
        Timestamp migliorTempo;


        public void setCorsia(Integer corsia) {
            this.corsia = corsia;
        }

        public void setGiro(Integer giro) {
            this.giro = giro;
        }
        public Timestamp getUltimoTempo() {
            return ultimoTempo;
        }
        public void setUltimoTempo(Timestamp ultimoTempo) {
            this.ultimoTempo = ultimoTempo;
        }
        public Timestamp getMigliorTempo() {
            return migliorTempo;
        }
        public void setMigliorTempo(Timestamp migliorTempo) {
            this.migliorTempo = migliorTempo;
        }

       public Macchina(int c, int g)
       {
           this.corsia=c;
           this.giro=g;
       }

       public int getCorsia(){
           return corsia;
       }

       public int getGiro(){
           return giro;
       }
    }
```

This class is used to stored the information for the car in the race.

Comment: `Map<Car,Position>`  ?

Comment: Your code is why I think English should be universal language even in programming when naming variables. Localized variables are evil when it comes to readability to others.

Comment: Yes, I have think to use this structure, but How can I detect the position of all car?

Comment: @bircastri By iterating over the Map.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that A car has a speed.
The track has the distance and cars on it. 
Your object design should reflect that.

Depending on how many properties a car has, you might not need a car object.

If you plan on extending your car racing program, you might want an abstract vehicle class. Especially if tracks become complicated, and cars become highly varied.

If you just want to find something like the position of a car at a discrete time and when a car reaches a certain distance then following might work for your purposes. 
Pseudo code:

```
track { 
int length, time, Maxtime;
array<int> carSpeeds, carPositions;
main(){
Maxtime=100;
 for(time=1; time<MaxTime; time++){
   for(int j= 0; j < carSpeeds.size(); j++){
      carPositions[j] = time*careSpeed // reset for each lap.
   // if position is greater than track length, you might have a winner or a tie. 
   }
 }
}
}
```

You can add in a max distance and other things.

If you want to eventually model warp capable space ship racing to various waypoints, submarine racing between underwater cities, and dirtbike racing with shortcuts, the code should have high cohesion, and low coupling. But the first of many iterations would probably look similar to the above.